# Friend functions, Data managing, OOP, Cpp

Tags: c++, performance, function, oop, friend

A curious question about the process of Friend Functions on Cpp.

Can we use **friend functions** as **setters** and **getters** (Manipulators, Accessors), or in other words, what is the **difference** between them, knowing that setters and getters are only for a specific using, and for underlying meaning, i'm talking abour **performances** and **robustness** too.

Thank you.

Comment: making a function `friend` of a class is about accessing private members, this has nothing to do with performance. For real OOP you don't need a single getter or setter btw.

Comment: The simple answer is that yes, you can use them for that. The difference between them is exactly the difference between methods and free functions.